# TableauException (40200): server did not call us back Python 3.6 in Docker Container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, tableau-api

I'm running the python tableausdk (`TableauSDK-10300.19.1013.2251`) in an `ubuntu:18.04` docker container on python 3.6. Whenever I try to use the SDK in a script it hangs and then I get the error in the title.

All the answers I've found for this problem elsewhere have not resolved my issue:
I

- have set the environment variables `TAB_SDK_LOGDIR` and
  `TAB_SDK_TMPDIR` to a directory in the container that has 755
  permissions.
- The tdeserver64 executable also has 755 permissions.
- Both the directory/file are owned by the user executing the script
- I can run the tdeserver64 executable in docker just fine by itself, it gives the following logs:

```
docker@e8983a5d7316:~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tableausdk/bin$ ./tdeserver64
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016): argv[0]="./tdeserver64"
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016): pid=29
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016): Machine Configuration
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   Max Descriptors: 1048576
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016): Vectorization Support
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   Supports SSE:    Yes
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   Supports SSE2:   Yes
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   Supports SSE3:   Yes
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   Supports SSE4.1: Yes
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   Supports SSE4.2: Yes
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   Supports AVX:    Yes
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   Supports AVX2:   Yes
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016): Adjusted Values
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   Physical RAM:              2085785600
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   CPUs available to process: 6
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   worker-threads:            6
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   max-concurrency:           3
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   query-parallelism:         3
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   min-query-parallelism:     2
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   work-buffer-size:          64
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   TrackingMappedFiles :      0
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   MemoryMapEntireFile:       1
2020-04-28 20:12:15.557 (140653577342016):   use-openfile-cache:        1
2020-04-28 20:12:15.558 (140653577342016): tdeserver: server listening for incoming connections at: tab.tcp://127.0.0.1:27042
```

What is keeping the server from communicating with my script?

**EDIT**

tableausdk works just fine in my docker container when I build a test extract directly in the python interpreter. When I exit the interpreter and try to run the same code in a script I still get this error. Seems to be an issue around running the code from a script.

Answer (score 0):

After more debugging I discovered that removing an import worked. I was also importing `google.cloud.bigquery` in this script, which for some reason would cause this behavior (they do a lot in that library when you import it).

Removing this import fixed this issue.